# python Ray: How to write to a file

Tags: python, ray

How can i construct a ray framework where each process will write it's results to a common file ? What i'm currently trying is :

```
import ray
import time
import pickle
import filelock
ray.init()

filename = 'data/db.pkl'



@ray.remote
def f(i):
    try:    
        with filelock.FileLock(filename):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                data = pickle.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}
    
    if i not in data.keys():

        # The actual computations that takes times and need to be parralell: here just a square.
        new_key = i
        new_item = i**2
        
        with filelock.FileLock(filename):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                data = pickle.load(file)

            data[new_key] = new_item
            with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                pickle.dump(data,file)
    return None


numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
rez = [f.remote(i) for i in numbers]
```

But i get an error.

How can i achieve this behavior ? I want each process to :
1° Check the database to see if it's work is needed
2° Work
3° Write it's result to the database.

Without locking the file, this work, but not all results are saved... How can i achieve the wanted behavior ? Note that later i'll need this to work on a distributed setup..

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, you should use `'ab'` (the *append* mode instead of `'wb'` for overwriting the file). With append mode you shouldn't need locking since it is [thread-safe](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) on a POSIX system.
2. What error did you get when using lock on the file?
3. Given that you will eventually make the program distributed, I think the easiest thing to do is to use `ray.put()` in your `f(i)` to store the data in Ray [shared memory](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/memory-management.html) and then write the objects out from the main program.

Comment: Finally, I found out that the locking filename shoudl be different that the file i way trying to access.. It worked like this. Finnaly, i moved the whole code to charm4py to be able to run on a cluster, it was quite easy. Thanks for the tip about `ray.put()`, I learned a lot reading the doc :)